# Singing without the songs meaning

Tags: fiqh, music, singing

I know that musical instruments are totally **HARAM** in islam. But i wanted to ask that what is we sing song without any musical instrument and the song doesn't have any bad meaning against islam. Is it allowed?

And the most important thing that what if we sing a song (without any musical instrument) which is in a different language and we don't know its meaning, can we sing?

Hope you get my question.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. As to your statements: are instrument totally haram? Do you have any evidence for that?

Answer (score -2):

Singing or listening music or playing instruments is haram is all cases, no matter what the purpose is.

"And of the people is he who buys the amusement of speech to mislead [others] from the way of Allah without knowledge and who takes it in ridicule. Those will have a humiliating punishment." - Holy Quran, Surah 31, Ayah 6

And when they hear ill speech, they turn away from it and say, " For us are our deeds, and for you are your deeds. Peace will be upon you; we seek not the ignorant." - Holy Quran, Surah 28, Ayah 55

Hadhrat Abu Maalik Ashari (radiyallahu anhu) says that he heard Rasulullah (salallahu alaihi wassallam) say: "Most certainly, there will be in my Ummah people who will make lawful fornication, silk, liquor and musical instruments." (Bukhaari)

Hadhrat Abu Hurairah (radiyallahu anhu) narrates: "Rasulullah (salallahu alaihi wassallam) said: 'Verily, the bell is of the musical instruments of Shaitaan." (Muslim and Abu Dawood)